# What witnesses do i need for Rabin-Miller test for numbers up to 10¹⁸?

Tags: primes, primality-test

What set of witnesses is sufficient for the Miller-Rabin test to be correct for all numbers up to 10¹⁸? I know that use of primes up to 17 as witnesses suffices for n < 341550071728321.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/) record page, the set of 7 SPRP bases: `{2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, 1795265022}` is sufficient for a deterministic test to at least `n = 2^64 ( > 10^19)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A006945), use of witnesses up to 23 suffices for numbers up to 3825123056546413051

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a Baillie-Wagstaff test instead of a Miller-Rabin test, it has been certified to be error-free in classifying primes up to 2^64. The coding is not much more complicated, the function executes more quickly than a Miller-Rabin test, and there are no known errors of classification.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.